# How to select a date in Flex datechooser using TestComplete

Tags: apache-flex, vbscript, testcomplete

We are testing a Flex application using TestComplete Tool.  The tool is able to recognize all the fields inside the Flex application. As part of this, we need to select dates (DateChooser object) for few of the fields in a Form.

**Issue**: We are selecting the date in the datechooser object by setting the "selectedDate" property.

**fromDate.FlexObject.selectedDate = aqDateTime.Today**

The selected date appears in the UI for the fromDate field.On submitting the form, we are getting error message as "fromDate field is empty".

Do we need to set any additional fields to register the selected date?

We are using VBScript as scripting language in the Test Complete Tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that a required event is not fired when the value is set programmatically (e.g. OnKeyPress or something like that). You need to make your test type the date to the field in order to make this event work:

```
fromDate.FlexObject.selectedDate.Keys "6/2/2014"
```